# ARM Board with true video acceleration support

Tags: sbc

I would like to buy an ARM board that has true hardware video acceleration decoding for H.264, H.265 & VP8/9 and also has all required software drivers for linux available.

I tried boards like Asus TinkerBoard and.. They sell them claiming that have H.264 & H.264 decoding acceleration but at the moment of truth, it turns out that they lack/poorly have the software part. So it's basically useless.